# Xamarin Forms Custom SearchbarRenderer with Loadingcircle like Netflix

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I really want to implement a loading circle in the searchbar (overriding the cancel button while loading) on android like Netflix.

Currently Im getting the cancel button with

```
var searchBttId = searchView.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
var imbCancel = (searchView.FindViewById(searchBttId) as Android.Widget.ImageView)
```

but I dont know how to add a progresscircle and how to interact with it. I thought of adding it with AddView, but nothing pops up when testing.

Test:

```
var _v = new Android.Widget.ImageView(Context) { };
_v.SetBackgroundColor(new Android.Graphics.Color(200, 0, 0));
var c = new LayoutParams(500, 500);
_v.LayoutParameters = c;
searchView.AddView(_v);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I really want to implement a loading circle in the searchbar (overriding the cancel button while loading) on android like Netflix.

According to your description, you want to override searchbar's search_close_btn using other icon, like loading circle? Am I right?

If yes, I suggest you can use custom render to change searchbar's search_close_btn image.

Firstly, create custom Searchbar that inherit SearchBar in Form.cs.

```
public  class MySearchBar:SearchBar
{

}
```

Then implementing custom render in Android platform.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MySearchBar), typeof(MySearchBarRenderer))]
namespace demo3.Droid
{
 public class MySearchBarRenderer: SearchBarRenderer
{
    public MySearchBarRenderer(Context context):base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            var searchView = Control;

            int searchViewCloseButtonId = Control.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
            var closeIcon = searchView.FindViewById(searchViewCloseButtonId);
            (closeIcon as ImageView).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.plu3);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Please see the gif:

[image]

About Custom Render, you can take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I still have the problem with a loading circle (animation). I tried to override it with both .xml and .gif via                 imbCancel.SetImageDrawable(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.testloading)); but none worked for animation. The second problem I have is to toggle the animation when I am updating the search results. Right now it takes ~100ms for it to get a response from the get request, so I want to easily toggle the animation.